# Is the nonnegative orthant a "convex polyhedral cone"?

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, polyhedra, convex-geometry, convex-cone

I am currently studying [*Convex Optimization* by Boyd and Vandenberghe](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/). Chapter **2.2.4 Polyhedra** gives the following description of a **nonnegative orthant**:

> **Example 2.4** The *nonnegative orthant* is the set of points with nonnegative components, i.e.,
>
> $$\mathbf{R}^n_+ = \{ x \in \mathbf{R}^n \mid x_i \ge 0, i = 1, \dots, n \} = \{ x \in \mathbf{R}^n \mid x \succeq 0 \}.$$
>
> (Here $\mathbf{R}_+$ denotes the set of nonnegative numbers: $\mathbf{R}_+ = \{ x \in \mathbf{R} \mid x \ge 0 \}$.) The nonnegative orthant is a polyhedron and a cone (and therefore called a *polyhedral cone*).

Chapter **2.1.5 Cones** gives the following description of a **cone** and **convex cone**:

> A set $C$ is called a *cone*, or *nonnegative homogeneous*, if for every $x \in C$ and $\theta \ge 0$ we have $\theta x \in C$. A set $C$ is a *convex cone* if it is convex and a cone, which means that for any $x_1, x_2 \in C$ and $\theta_1, \theta_2 \ge 0$, we have
>
> $$\theta_1 x_1 + \theta_2 x_2 \in C$$

It seems to me that, not only is the nonnegative orthant a polyhedron and a cone, but it is also a *convex* cone? So it would be a "convex polyhedral cone"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exist convex cones that are not polyhedral (since they are not $\it{finite} $ intersection of hyperplanes). For instance, the cone $\{(x,y,z)\ \mid \ x^2 + y^2 \le z^2 \}$. Another very important example is the (convex) cone of positive semidefinite matrices.

Comment: But the existence of the cones of the type that you described does not preclude that this is a case of a convex polyhedral cone, right?

Comment: @The Pointer: I see what you are inquiring about... Well, any polyhedron is convex, so there is no need to add the word convex if the cone is also polyhedral. Basically: polyhedral cone is also convex cone,  but not conversely.

Comment: ok, it all makes sense now. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @orangeskid: I agree that "convex" sometimes is being subsumed (as in the example of the question), but there are authors too, which include non-convex examples into their definition of polyhedra (e.g. the regular Kepler-Poinsot star polyhedra come to mind).

Comment: @Dr.Richard Klitzing:  I see.. In that case there are obviously non convex polyhedral cones.